# gqlQuerry comparing datetime objects

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, gqlquery

Here is the relevant code copied from my application on GAE.

```
today = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_variable, "%d/%m/%Y")
yesterday = ref_today - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
tomorrow = ref_today + datetime.timedelta(days=1)
logging.info('%s  :  %s  :  %s', yesterday, today, tomorrow)
#2016-02-19 00:00:00  :  2016-02-20 00:00:00  :  2016-02-21 00:00:00

records = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM ProgrammeQueue"
         " WHERE scheduledFrom < :1 AND scheduledFrom > :2 "
         " ORDER BY scheduledFrom DESC", 
         tomorrow, yesterday)
```

Problem Statement :
Output:    all records of 19/02/2016 and 20/02/2016
Expected:  records = all records of 20/02/2016

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You query states:

```
WHERE scheduledFrom < :tomorrow AND scheduledFrom > :yesterday
```

where tomorrow and yesterday are datetimes. the time is set to 00:00:00, so the results will include dates of 19/02/2016 where the time is greater than 
00:00:00.

maybe your query should be rewritten to use date objects not datetime objects (depending on your model definition). or maybe you need to rewrite it to something like this:

```
records = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM ProgrammeQueue"
         " WHERE scheduledFrom < :1 AND scheduledFrom >= :2 "
         " ORDER BY scheduledFrom DESC", 
         tomorrow, today)
```

Comment: computation code changed as yesterday=today-datetime.timedelta(microseconds=1) .   It worked.   Thank you very much for pointing out the gross logical error in the code.  My model holds future data too.